# Create and free FMX components inside a TPanel at runtime

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

The below errors happen only when testing under MacOS. Under Windows it seems to work. I'm trying to display a dynamic list of strings into a TPanel, each inside it's own TPanel. The list of strings is kept in a TStringList object and everytime a new one is added or deleted, I'm calling a method to update the display by clearing what exists and then re-build the visual components. The update panel display method looks like this:

```
procedure TTestsScreen.UpdatePanelDisplay3;
var
  i : Integer;
  myPanel : TPanel;
  myLabel : TLabel;
  myImage : TImage;
begin
  //dispose of existig entities
  for i := (Length(search_entities_labels) - 1) downto 0 do
  begin
    search_entities_labels[i].Free;
    search_entities_labels[i]:= nil;
  end;
  for i := (Length(search_entities_images) - 1) downto 0 do
  begin
    search_entities_images[i].Free;
    search_entities_images[i]:= nil;
  end;
  for i := (Length(search_entities_panels) - 1) downto 0 do
  begin
    search_entities_panels[i].Free;
    search_entities_panels[i]:= nil;
  end;
  //adjust dynamic arrays
  SetLength(search_entities_images,main_search_entities_string_list.Count);
  SetLength(search_entities_labels,main_search_entities_string_list.Count);
  SetLength(search_entities_panels,main_search_entities_string_list.Count);
  //rebuild
  for i := 0 to main_search_entities_string_list.Count-1 do
  begin
    myPanel:= TPanel.Create(Self);
    myPanel.Parent := Panel1;
    myPanel.Height:= 30;
    myPanel.Width:= Panel1.Width;
    myPanel.Position.X:= 0;
    myPanel.Position.Y:= i*30;
    search_entities_panels[i]:= myPanel;
    //
    myLabel:= TLabel.Create(Self);
    myLabel.Parent:= myPanel;
    myLabel.Text:= main_search_entities_string_list[i];
    myLabel.Width:= (3*myPanel.Width) / 4;//display left
    search_entities_labels[i]:= myLabel;
    //
    myImage:= TImage.Create(Self);
    myImage.Parent:= myPanel;
    myImage.Tag:= i;
    myImage.Width:= 15;
    myImage.Height:= 15;
    myImage.Position.X:= myPanel.Width - myImage.Width;//display right
    myImage.MultiResBitmap.Assign(AppResources.delete_white_image.MultiResBitmap);
    myImage.OnClick:= DeleteSearchEntity;
    search_entities_images[i]:= myImage;
  end;
  //
  Panel1.Height:= 30 * main_search_entities_string_list.Count;
end;
```

I'm adding new elements into the panel like this:

```
procedure TTestsScreen.AddClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  main_search_entities_string_list.Add(DateTimeToStr(now));
  UpdatePanelDisplay3;
end;
```

The adding process works fine, with no errors. The problem is that when I try to delete an element like this

```
procedure TTestsScreen.DeleteSearchEntity(Sender: TObject);
begin
  main_search_entities_string_list.Delete((Sender as TImage).Tag);
  UpdatePanelDisplay3;
end;
```

I'm randomly getting

```
Runtime error 231
```

or

```
Exception EAccessViolation in module TestApp at 00039F33.
Access violation at address 00E7BBBC, accessing address 00000158.
Runtime error   0 at 00039F33
```

Inside the FormCreate event I'm doing

```
procedure TTestsScreen.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetLength(search_entities_labels,0);
  SetLength(search_entities_images,0);
  SetLength(search_entities_panels,0);
  main_search_entities_string_list:= TStringList.Create;
end;
```

The arrays are declared as

```
search_entities_labels : array of TLabel;
search_entities_images : array of TImage;
search_entities_panels : array of TPanel;
```

Comment: What if instead of using sized arrays you try with generics... TObjectList<TLabel>, for example? That would simplify the code a lot. But I think your real problem is that you want to free a visual component from within one of its eventhandlers... that's a no-no. An OnClick event handler is an awfully wrong place to destroy the sender of the event.

Comment: @Frazz, just tried deferring the UpdatePanelDisplay3 to a manually triggered event (after deleting from the TStringList) and the error doesn't happen anymore. What would be the best approach to do the visual deletion automatically? Thanks.

Comment: The best approach is to use the event handler to enqueue a deletion message and then process the message in the UI thread when there is time.

Comment: @Frazz, can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be Freeing a component from within an event handler that is being called by the component itself. In this case you are Freeing a TImage from within its OnClick event handler.

You have to split this operation in two phases.

**Phase 1**

In the event handler you either enqueue a message for the form or you just flag the component set (Image, Label and Panel) as **"To Be Deleted"**. You can do this many ways... by keeping a list of components to be deleted... or of indexes into the array or TObjectList that contains them.

**Phase 2**

In the form, when you have time, you finally Free the unneeded components. You can do this when you receive the enqueued message (if you chose that technique) or you can use Application.OnIdle (if you just flagged them for deletion).

A further notice... I spoke of enqueued messages, which is IMHO the best solution. Beware that standard FireMonkey messages are not enqueued in an asynchronous way, but are immediately dispatched in a synchronous way. So they cannot solve your problem... you have to use TThread.Queue to snap out of the empasse.

Answer (score 0):

When you create these controls with:

```
myPanel:= TPanel.Create(Self)
```

The `self` means that the form owns the control, so you can't call free on it because then the parent (the panel) doesn't know it's gone.

You'll want to change that to the panel.

Comment: That's not really true. A component notifies it's owner that it is being destroyed. It is not a good habit to Free a component that has an Owner... but it should work. Usually you set the Owner to have it take care of the components life cycle. If you intend to do it yourself, you can create the new component with a nil owner. But this is all just best practice... not a must do.

Comment: At least I know it works fine in VCL. I don't recall trying in FMX, but I would think it has the same behavior, considering they still root from `TComponent`.